# How to swap from MTKView to UIView display seamlessly

Tags: swift, uiview, synchronization, metal, metalkit

I have an MTKView whose contents I draw into a UIView.  I want to swap display from MTKView to UIView without perceptible changes.  How to achieve?

Currently, I have

```
let strokeCIImage = CIImage(mtlTexture: metalTextureComposite...) // get MTLTexture
let imageCropCG = cicontext.createCGImage(strokeCIImage...) // convert to CGImage
let layerStroke = CALayer() // create layer
layerStroke.contents = imageCropCG // populate with CGImage
strokeUIView.layer.addSublayer(layerStroke)  // add to view
strokeUIView.layerWillDraw(layerStroke) //heads up to strokeUIView
```

and a delegate method within layerWillDraw() that clears the MTKView.

```
strokeViewMetal.metalClearDisplay()
```

The result is that I'll see a frame drop every so often in which nothing is displayed.

In the hopes of cleanly separating the two tasks, I also tried the following:

```
let dispatchWorkItem = DispatchWorkItem{
      print("lyr add start")
      self.pageCanvasImage.layer.addSublayer(sublayer)
      print("lyr add end")
 }

let dg = DispatchGroup()

DispatchQueue.main.async(group: dg, execute: dispatchWorkItem)
//print message when all blocks in the group finish
dg.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
   print("dispatch mtl clear")
   self.strokeCanvasMetal.setNeedsDisplay()  // clear MTKView
}
```

The idea being add the new CALayer to UIImageView, and THEN clear the MTKView. 
Over many screen draws, I *think* this result in fewer frame drops during the View swap, but I'd like a foolproof solution with NO drops. Basically what I'm after is to only clear strokeViewMetal once strokeUIView is ready to display. Any pointers would be appreciated

Comment: An `MTKView` already is-a `UIView`. Why aren't you just displaying the `MTKView` directly? If you want to overlay one over the other, just make the top one non-opaque, use a clear color to draw its background, and do rendering as normal. Make the top one a subview of the other, with a frame matching the other's bounds.

Comment: Thank you Ken.  The design of the app i'm working on requires me to save what i draw in MTKView into a growing array of CALayers (possibly hundreds).  This means I have to do this switch at some point.  I suppose I could look into doing the same with CAMetal layers, but am not sure if I'll run into GPU memory issues.  With CALayers, I can easily populate from CPU memory or from disk images. Would you have any suggestions?

Comment: First, I recommend that you render into a texture of your own, not the drawable's texture. Then, draw one big quad textured with your texture to the drawable's texture. That way, you don't need to read from the drawable's texture or rely on its state (like whether it's being reused for new drawing or cleared). You can maintain a small pool of your textures so that you don't reuse one for rendering until you're done creating an image from it.

Comment: I will try your idea out once I exhaust the possibility of a simple approach.  To this end, I edited the question to include another approach which looks promising, but is still not perfect.  Would you have any comments on it?  I certainly appreciate your time.

Comment: So, there are three separate but related sources of asynchronicity. One is the Metal rendering to the texture. You can use a completed handler on the command buffer to react to that. The next is the presentation of the drawable. That also waits for commands that write to the texture (although not necessarily the whole buffer) to complete and then may also wait for the current Core Animation transaction to be flushed. Finally, your manipulation of your layer also waits for a (possibly different) CA transaction to be flushed.

Comment: I suspect your blank frames are because you're reading the texture before the rendering has completed. You should only do it after the command buffer has completed. For the next frame (including the clear), you should be using a new drawable, which will have a different texture. So, the clear should not affect the texture that you're reading from, regardless when it happens.

Comment: Thank you again Ken.   I suspect you are right about the synchronicity issues you point out.  I'm not sure quite what to do about it, but in the meantime I'm going to see if I can come up with an MTKView only implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Synchronicity issues between MTKView and UIView are resolved for 99% of my tests when I set MTKView's `presentsWithTransaction` property to true.  According to Apple's documentation:

> Setting this value to true changes this default behavior so that your
>   MTKView displays its drawable content synchronously, using whichever
>   Core Animation transaction is current at the time the drawable’s
>   present() method is called.

Once that is done, the draw loop has to be modified from:

```
commandEncoder.endEncoding()  
commandBuffer.present(drawable)  
commandBuffer.commit()
```

to:

```
commandEncoder.endEncoding()  
commandBuffer.commit()  
commandBuffer.waitUntilScheduled()  // synchronously wait until the drawable is ready
drawable.present() // call the drawable’s present() method directly
```

This is done to prevent Core activities to end before we're ready to present MTKView's drawable.

With all of this set up, I can simply:

```
let strokeCIImage = CIImage(mtlTexture: metalTextureComposite...) // get MTLTexture
let imageCropCG = cicontext.createCGImage(strokeCIImage...) // convert to CGImage
let layerStroke = CALayer() // create layer
layerStroke.contents = imageCropCG // populate with CGImage
// the last two events will happen synchronously
strokeUIView.layer.addSublayer(layerStroke)  // add to view
strokeViewMetal.metalClearDisplay() // empty out MTKView
```

With all of this said, I do see overlapping of the views every now and then, but at a much, much lower frequency